# How to authenticate a machine only once?

Tags: firefox, authentication, mac-address

I need to authenticate a machine only once saying this machine can access my SAAS. I use aspx.net and now use Super cookies to authenticate a machine. But while clearing the cookies even the shared folder's cookies are getting deleted and so the Super cookies too.

So now I'd prefer to authenticate a machine by using its MAC address. I couldn't find any successful way to do it. Also found that MAC addresses can be easily spoofed.

Can any one suggest me a way to solve this problem?

PS: As most of my clients use Firefox , I was even thinking of developing a FF extension to authenticate and make my clients install the extension. Does this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) I think is very suited for the problem you're describing.